# Connecting a MySQL database to Glassfish classpath is not set or classname is wrong

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm swapping out a derby database for a MySQL one. I had everything working before but after what I thought was the proper configuration I'm getting the error:

Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource

Full error output from console:

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:292)
at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:114)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactory.java:1292)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:148)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:101)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
```

I've double checked some of the names, the connection pool and other resources.I've also added the MySQL driver .jars to the library of glassfish in both projects. The database was definitely working correctly through eclipse because I was able to view tables and display the resources inside the database context of eclipse. So I know that at least THOSE drivers are working correcly. Also the persistence.xml file looks good. it references the jdbc/mydatabase  jndi reference like it should and default JTA is selected as the manament type.

Does anyone have another suggestion?  Thank you

Comment: It says almost the same thing:Ping Connection Pool for mysqlstatuspool is Failed. Ping failed Exception - Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Please check the server.log for more details. Ping failed Exception

Comment: I've never had to manually set the classpath for this connection pool when I was using the derby database so I'm hoping if some one thinks that is what I have to do they can explain where the resource is and how exactly to do that.

Comment: the datasource classname: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource  was autogenerated for me in the admin window so I did not select that and do not know from where it came.

Comment: My resource type is java.sql.Datasource

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> *I've also added the MySQL driver .jars to the library of glassfish in both projects.*

It was apparently not done right. The JAR has to go in `/glassfish/domains/[domainname]/lib/ext` folder of the Glassfish installation where `[domainname]` usually defaults to `domain1`. You can and should not configure it from the Eclipse side on.

Comment: Ok I did not add it that way. I added it by right clicking on the glassfish library in eclipse and in user libraries selecting the new connector library and selected my jar from there. I will try your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Gonna have to look at that Amazon list :P

Comment: Remembering that it's necessary to restart the instance after to take effect!

Answer (score 24):

Looks like I am replying very late, but however people who would be referring to this thread may find the following information being useful.  So I am posting it here:

1. Download the connector Jar from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html
2. unzip the pack and copy mysql-connector-java-verno-bin.jar
3. past the same at [GlassFish Installation Directory]/domains/[domain name]/lib folder
4. restart your domain and ping to check your connection in JDBC Connection Pools

There you go. If your MySql is running then it will ping the DB successfully

Comment: Restarting the domain did not refresh all of the additional properties of the connection pool. (I had created the pool before I copied the jar over.)

It might be helpful for someone to know that you should just recreate the pool after copying the jar over. Everything worked for me after I did that.

Answer (score 5):

I copied the jar file to `$glassfish_install_folder\glassfish\lib`, after that it worked. I use *glassfish 4.0*.

Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beamn/index.html) from oracle.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue in 2018 and would like to note that if you are using glassfish 4 (current is 5) then it seems you have to use the Connector/J 5.1.47 version for it to work. If you use the current version (Connector/J 8.0.13) then exception mentioned in the original question keeps appearing, no matter where you place the .jar file.

With Connector/J 5.1.47 it works perfectly.

Comment: issue is still present with Connector/J 8.0.17

Answer (score 1):

Solution is

*> asadmin add-library /path/to/mysql-connector-java-bin.jar*

Check this link:
https://blog.payara.fish/using-mysql-with-payara

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in 2019 and would like to note that if you are using docker image `payara/server-full` (I am using `5.194` so far) as I do the location to place the driver jar is:

`/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/production/lib/`

In the end I am doing something like this in the `Dockerfile` of payara server:

```
RUN wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mariadb/jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.2.0/mariadb-java-client-2.2.0.jar \
    -O /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/production/lib/mariadb-java-client-2.2.0.jar
```