# Connecting to h2 database with Glassfish

Tags: jdbc, glassfish-3, h2

I'm developing a web-app using Glassfish application server.
I have installed H2 DB and now trying to define a connection pool in glassfish but when trying to ping the DB it fails.

Here is what I did:

1. Installed H2 DB and created a new DB (server mode).
2. I added an H2 maven dependency in my pom.xml:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.166</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Copied H2 jar file (h2-1.3.166.jar) to my glassfish lib: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\lib
4. Loggd on to glassfish admin gui and created the following jdbc connection:

   - Resource type: javax.sql.DataSource
   - Database Driver Vendor: H2
   - Datasource Classname: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource

My "additional properties" are:

- user:  my_db_user
- password:  my_db_password
- url:  jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/my_db_name;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE

When I try to ping this connection it fails with message:

Ping Connection Pool failed for myCpool. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.

The full log says:

`Wrong class name or classpath for Datasource Object java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:285) at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:114) at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactory.java:1307) at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:163) at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102) at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:697) at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:426) at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1086) at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:130) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateExecCommand.executeCommand(TemplateExecCommand.java:127) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateCommandGetResource.processGet(TemplateCommandGetResource.java:78) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148) at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

Have I missed something?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource` means the H2 JDBC driver is not in the classpath. I don't know Glassfish very well, but it seems it's not in the classpath. It seems similar problems occurred with other database drivers, [for example MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349970/connecting-a-mysql-database-to-glassfish-classpath-is-not-set-or-classname-is-wr) (the .jar file needs to be added to `/glassfish/domains/[domainname]/lib/ext`)

You need to use a different database URL:

```
jdbc:h2:~/my_db_name;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

[As described in the documentation, the automatic mixed mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode) does not require or work with server URLs (URLs starting with `jdbc:h2:tcp://`)

Comment: Thank you. The AUTO_SERVER=TRUE is an addition in which i've added as a part my million shots of trying to make it work. It's the same with or without it (but your comment is taken, better off I guess). Regarding the ClassNotFoundException - I added the H2 jar (using maven) and I can sure see the jar under my Maven Dependencies folder (so it should be available under my classpath I believe). Shouldn't this jar contain the driver? When the application server (glassfish in this case) points to classpath does it refer to the same classpath as my web-application classpath?

Comment: The jar file does contain the driver. Only, I don't know how to add the jar file to the Glassfish classpath... I found a similar problem (with solution), I updated my answer - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349970/connecting-a-mysql-database-to-glassfish-classpath-is-not-set-or-classname-is-wr - but I'm not sure if this will solve the problem. You may find other (StackOverflow) questions and answers however.

Comment: The link in which you have provided me with has solved the issue! It seemed that I put the jar under \glassfish3\glassfish\lib but this is a wrong location. The correct location, as mentiond in the link you have provided me with is: /glassfish/domains/[domainname]/lib/ext.  Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the driver jar file for h2 in the following path in your server installation folder:

```
glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
```