# Unable to Connect to JDBC Connection Pool from Glassfish

Tags: mysql, sql, glassfish

I am running GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5) with MySql

I have created a JDBC Connection Pool using NetBeans.

Googled this problem I found that adding it is a classpath issue.
[Connecting a MySQL database to Glassfish classpath is not set or classname is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349970/connecting-a-mysql-database-to-glassfish-classpath-is-not-set-or-classname-is-wr)
 and 
http://bhapca.blogspot.in/2009/06/class-name-is-wrong-or-classpath-is-not.html
Added the jar in the directory.

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib
```

and also tried in

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext
```

Restarted the server many times. Re-created connection pool .Still No Success.

I get this when i try pinging it from Admin Console

```
Error An error has occurred
Ping Connection Pool failed for AffableBeanPool. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.
```

related server log entry:

```
Log Entry Detail

Timestamp

Jul 15, 2013 15:45:49.340
Log Level

WARNING
Logger

javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service
Name-Value Pairs

_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;
Record Number

3172
Message ID

RAR8054
Complete Message

Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ AffableBeanPool ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
```

and

```
Log Entry Detail

Timestamp

Jul 15, 2013 15:39:33.777
Log Level

SEVERE
Logger

javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.util
Name-Value Pairs

_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=Thread-2;
Record Number

3153
Message ID

Complete Message

RAR5099 : Wrong class name or classpath for Datasource Object java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:285) at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:114) at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactory.java:1307) at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:163) at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102) at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:697) at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:426) at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1086) at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:130) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateExecCommand.executeCommand(TemplateExecCommand.java:127) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateCommandGetResource.processGet(TemplateCommandGetResource.java:78) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147) at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148) at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: `Still No Success.` - what are you actually trying to do? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: `Please check the server.log for more details`! What are the server.log files saying? I'm using a MySQL pool with the `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource` without any problems. Cheers

Comment: @Andreas Please have a look. Added error message.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You've placed the jdbc jar in domain folder, try putting it in the Glassfish server folder.
`C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\lib`

Answer (score 7):

Right, you lack mysql lib find and download mysql-connector-java-5.x.x-bin.jar copy to `E:\Projects\glassfish3.1.1\glassfish\lib` then restart server and enjoy !!!

Comment: That file is already in that folder for me but I am still getting  Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQLPool. null Please check the server.log for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The data source factory has moved to a different package in *Connector/J 8.0.* It can now be found inside `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource`

So you need to change Datasource Classname as mentioned above.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. In addition, in my case I used Payara and I had to specify also the useSSL=false parameter to make the ping work: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2747 .

Answer (score 1):

You can put yor mysql connector jar at this place.
It works for me
E:\servers\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib