# GlassFish 5 and MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, glassfish, mysql-connector

I use GlassFish 5 with `mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar`

and `CLASSPATH` values:

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish5\glassfish\lib 
C:\Program Files\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib 
C:\Program Files\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext
```

After several restarts of both the server and the laptop it still gives this error:

> Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQL_sakila. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMxZe.png)

The issue is similar to this [StackOverflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651423/unable-to-connect-to-jdbc-connection-pool-from-glassfish/53377491#53377491) but I have applied the answers there and none of them have helped.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

```
Datasource Classname: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
```

Two new "Additional Properties" to the JDBC Connection Pool :

```
useSSL = false 
serverTimezone = UTC (this is not even true in my case, I am UTC+2)
```

Here one remark : when I installed MySQL instance, I expressly set it NOT to use SSL for the passwords from the option in the installer on the regarding page.

other "Additonal Properties " are :

```
password = myPass 
databaseName = sakila 
serverName = localhost 
user = root 
networkProtocol = jdbc 
portNumber = 3306
```

.. and it succeeded

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me too. Exellente! Although I used the

`com.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` on **Netbeans** as my Datasource name but I think setting `useSSL= false` is real thing.

But I used `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` on glassfish server