# Class name is wrong or classpath is not set ERROR in Netbeans with Glassfish 5 server and JPAs

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, server-error

I have a Web Application in Netbeans 11 (with JDK 8 installed), I have added the dependencies for mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar and I have generated the JPAs from my DB.

No error while building it.

But when I try to run it, the Glassfish server give me these [errors (pastebin link)](https://pastebin.com/BS0u32wk).

This is my persistence.xml, that I set accordingly, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="InvoicesPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/Invoices</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And in my java class I call it by:

```
@Stateless
public class InvoiceEJB implements InvoiceEJBLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "InvoicesPU")
    EntityManager em;
    ...
    em.someMethod();
```

For completeness, I have no error during the compilation phase!

Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**After some research I solved it in this way:**

1. taking inspiration from a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378880/glassfish-5-and-mysql-connector), I created the Connection Pool and the Resource in the Glassfish Admin Console as suggested by [devmind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11095701/devmind) following [this](https://javatutorial.net/configure-glassfish-mysql).
2. I removed as dependency the `mysql-connector-java-8.x.x.jar` and I added the `mysql-connector-java-5.x.x.jar`
3. In `the persistence.xml` I set the JNDI name for the tag `jta-data-source`

And everything goes as expected!

I don't know how to make everything work with the latest version of the MySQL Connector but, at least, in this way my Web Application works.

**EDIT:** for latests versions of mysql-connector, as [devmind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11095701/devmind) has suggest you should set MysqlDataSource: from `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` as reported [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html).

I hope it's useful to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put your JDBC driver jar to Glassfish domain's `lib` folder. I usually store them in `lib/ext`.

Comment: I checked, in the Glassfish domain there is already the mysql-connector driver!

Comment: I fount this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378880/glassfish-5-and-mysql-connector) and I checked and all the things about glassfish and jdbc in the Services window are now ok, but I don't know how to add the `Datasource Classname: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` part. Where can I add it???

Comment: Does Ping work for your connection pool in GF admin console?

Comment: Probably I don't have the correct Connection Pool in Glassfish, I have only [these](https://imgur.com/a/saziMMH)

Comment: Create connection pool and JDBC resource. You can refer to [this tutorial](https://javatutorial.net/configure-glassfish-mysql). Resource JNDI name goes to `jta-data-source` tag:
`<jta-data-source>jdbc/tutorialsDS</jta-data-source>`

Comment: Ok, I created the Connection Pool and the Resource now! And set the additional properties and the `jta-data-source` tag. But in the Admin Console of Glassfish, in the Connection Pool newly created if I test it with Ping... it says me [that](https://imgur.com/a/0bXVptB) Have I forgot something?

Comment: Solved! I removed as dependency the `mysql-connector-java-8.x.x.jar` and I addet the `mysql-connector-java-5.x.x.jar` and everything goes fine. I don't know how to solve with the newest connector! :_(

Comment: Class names were changed in version 8. Change data source classname from `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource`. Check [connector docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember if I got this info from some other post or from the Glassfish user manual but it solves the issue mentioned for me, i.e.: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set ERROR with Glassfish 5 or Payara  server. I'm using `Payara Server 5.2022.3` currently.

Add the latest connector j to your server/your_domain; in my case it is domain1 and this is the script after I `cd` to `/bin`:
`C:\Program Files\payara-web-5.2022.3\payara5\bin>asadmin add-library --type app "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar`"

Where quoted string is the path where I keep my connector j.